# Get Adjacency Matrix from QGIS (Italian Railway)

Tags: python, graph, shapefile, qgis, adjacency-matrix

I should conduct an activity which expects to operate with a weighted, directed graph. In particular, the graph has to represent the Italian railway network.
I managed to obtain the network on a specified layer, on QGIS, and I can export it in various formats like .shp, .shx, .geojsonl.json etc.
The question regards, from any of these files, **how to get an adjacency, in order to create the graph I need** (or simply create the graph, from which I may extract the matrix).

I found a [networknx Python function](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-2.3/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html) that allows to generate a Directed Graph from a shape file (.shp).
The problem is that it's deprecated and no longer available since the 3.0 version of networknx package. Moreover, I didn't find any alternative.

May someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you export it to a text file with comma, space or tab delimited values?